# Unhandled Lockdown error (-20) while connecting to iPhone, tried several solutions on the net (listed below)

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to get my iphone to connect to my computer running on Ubuntu and get Lockdown error (-20).

I tried:

```
idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair 

sudo mkdir /var/lib/lockdown
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/lockdown

removing .plist file
```

Installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils ifuse
```

Comment: did you unlock the iphone?

Comment: yes, of course, I unlocked and trusted the computer

Comment: just making sure ;-) I keep only finding the 2 things you posted with the edit :P

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?  I'm in the same position as you.